# How can I make it clear that this question is about one general procedure, not asking for specific repair advice?

Tags: discussion

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/173062/how-can-i-identify-this-burned-out-part

A pack of trolls attacked this question, claiming it was a cleverly disguised repair question trying to sneak by the moderators. "The issues I find with repair questions include:"

> The OP has no electronics experience and can only say "it's not working."

I in fact have some electronics experience and I have gone to the trouble of specifically identifying a single component to serve as a convenient example; however, the question is one of procedure to identify an unknown component and thus may be applicable to anyone.

> The device contains proprietary/custom chips (no documentation)

The device in question is a simple discrete component.

> The circuit needs specialized equipment and knowledge for debugging

This question does not involve an entire circuit... merely the procedure for identifying a single discrete component.

> The circuit is part of a module that is in a "throw-away" circuit.

This question is about procedure to identify an unknown discrete component.

> It's really dead (wrong power supply voltage, lightning, blunt force trauma)

It's really easy. This is not a question asking to fix anything.

> The complexity of the circuit and debugging is beyond what is reasonable.

It's a question about procedure to identify one discrete component!
Rather than be overly broad such that the question would take a book to answer, the question is focused with a specific example used as a prop.

I have expended a tremendous amount of effort trying to make it clear that this is not a repair question, nevertheless the obtuse trolls are having a field day pretending it is a repair question and have gone so far as to flag it for deletion. What more can I say to make it clear that repair advice is not being sought?
Although the procedure being asked for can certainly be used as a step in repairs, it is also useful in reverse engineering, reusing parts, etc. It is not a repair question. The information being sought is so much more useful and to a broader audience.

Comment: Step 1: Don't be a dick.

Answer (score 14):

Your question, as posed, was far too broad for the question-and-answer format used on this site. In fact, in its broadest sense, it would require a complete education in electrical engineering in order to answer it.

Therefore, the people who responded looked for clues about the context in which you were asking the question in order to figure out what kind of answer you were looking for, and the only clues you provided were some incredibly bad, out-of-focus pictures of a dead power supply. This told the responders a couple of things:

- You are seeking to repair a power supply.
- You know next to nothing about the design of such power supplies.
- You are not a careful or detail-oriented person.

These assumptions are what set the tone for the responses you received. Admittedly, some of those responses were rather harsh, because responders can be rather frustrated by questions of this type, since they're explicitly off-topic for this site.

The situation escalated when, in response to the initial comments, you obstinately insisted that it was NOT a repair question, yet you continued to provide no further clues about what information you were really looking for. These responses gave some additional clues:

- You don't respond well to constructive criticism, possibly failing to recognize it.
- You are a difficult person with whom to have a productive conversation.

This is how we ended up where we are now.

---

To give a partial meta-answer to your actual question, there are two sets of specifications for any component: The set of *minimum* specifications it must meet for the application in which it is being used, and the set of *actual* specifications that it was given by the manufacturer.

The first set is determined by the circuit designer, and this is why you'd need a full EE education in order to determine this set. Part of the job of the circuit designer is to use this set of requirements to select an actual component from a manufacturer, making sure that each relevant specification of the selected component meets or exceeds the requirements of the circuit.

The second set of specifications can only be found by looking up the datasheet for the component that is published by the manufacturer. In order to find this, you need to know who the manufacturer is and the exact part number by which the manufacturer identifies the component. If you can't get this information from the component itself (e.g., because of physical damage), then you need to find the documentation for the assembly in which it was used (e.g., the Bill of Materials) in order to get it.

So, if you want to improve your question, you first need to make it clear *which set of specifications you're interested in*. It would help to know why you're looking for this information, and also to give some information about your own background (e.g., education and experience), so that a concise answer tailored to your needs can be formulated.

Comment: This answer is offensive. The answer should address the difficulties of the question, NOT suggest that the asker is difficult.

Comment: "Your question, as posed, was far too broad for the question-and-answer format used on this site." 

It asks a single question: how to do something simple.

"In fact, in its broadest sense,"

Why would you choose to interpret it broadly when a strict reading would result in an acceptable question?

"it would require a complete education in electrical engineering in order to answer it."

Are we to design our questions so that uneducated idiots can answer?

Comment: Interesting. To be honest, I didn't think you'd be coming back. These comments simply support the last two bullet points in my answer. My answer is all about your question, and if you can't see that, then there's probably nothing more we can do for you here on this site.

Comment: "You are a difficult person with whom to have a productive conversation."
"My answer is all about your question"
Your words and your assertion do not agree. We call this lying in my culture.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said, "it would require *giving you* a complete education in electrical engineering in order to answer it." Is that clearer?

Comment: "To be honest, I didn't think you'd be coming back"
So you are not usually honest? And may I take this as evidence that you were trolling me to run me off? Your clique is in danger of being infiltrated! Oh word.

Comment: The answer remains offensive. I suppose that is a reflection of the author. I suggest you edit it.

Comment: I notice that you aren't denying my first three bullet points, so I guess they're on the mark. They explain why your question was closed so  quickly. Have you read the second part of my answer above? It explains one reason that your question is too broad. Or are you too busy being offended to have a reasonable conversation about that?

Comment: Asking how to infer the specs of a component from just a board is not a repair question. That you say it is, after all your other dishonesty, says more about you.

Comment: I am not obligated to respond to your every troll point in order for such hate and dishonesty to be known for what it is--baiting.

Comment: "first need to make it clear which set of specifications you're interested in."  This could easily have been asked in the comments section, which is what the comments are for. They are not for trolling the new guys, which is what you have used them for.

Comment: OK, I think we're done here.

Answer (score 9):

I agree that asking how to infer the specs of a component from just a board is not strictly speaking a repair question.  However, it's not a good question for this site for the same reason we ban repair questions.  In some limited cases, such questions *might* be OK, but due to being right on the line need to be extra carefully written and you need to ask about a part for which some specs can actually be inferred.

Clarity of presentation, respect for those you seek a favor from, and general attitude matter - **a lot**.  Don't understimate how much these things will sway a decision as to whether a question is on topic and whether to downvote, especially in borderline cases.  When you thumb your nose at people, they are going to look for the electronic equivalent ways of saying *up yours*, which on this site is voting to close and downvoting to oblivion.

Specific problems with the original version of your question were:

The pictures are links.  No, we're mostly not going to chase down links to get immediately important information to answering a question.

The component in question is not one for which the specs can be easily identified.

I didn't follow any of the links (again, not gonna happen), but the two pictures that were added to your question two edits later were abysmal in quality.  The one of the bottom of the board was severly wobbled.  The one of the top of the board showed the part in question as only a small blurry blob.  In addition, it had a strong and annoying yellow cast.  Your text mentions the component being green, but what is pointed to by the red lines doesn't look green.

Stop and actually *think* about how crappy pictures or crappy text (your question isn't guilty of this one, but it applies generally) are perceived by the volunteers that you hope will answer your question.  It says *"Eh, you lot don't matter.  A minute or two to take better pictures or clean up the ones I have isn't worth my trouble since you are here to serve me.  Now fork over answers already, you peons!"*.

You included a picture of your cat.  Seriously!!?  This is a question and answer site, not a kaffeklatsch.

Reasons 1 and 2 made the question difficult to answer, and pushed it towards the kind of question that just doesn't work well on this site.  Reasons 3 and 4 pissed people off, so instead of looking for ways to give you some slack and try to make this question work, they instead thought *"Screw this jerk"*, and looked for justification to close and downvote, which were not hard to find.

Nick gave you about as good a answer in a comment as was possible for this question, even if it had been asked more clearly and respectfully.

You then compounded the problem and sealed your fate by making snippy comments instead of addressing the issues:

> That you can't understand that says you didn't read the question very thoroughly.

> You trolls need to take a hike.

> I don't know how it's possible to deal with such daft people without contempt. You're all obviously trolling me.

> It was my first question and I am astounded at how the sharks managed to sniff fresh blood. No noob question must go unmolested, eh? We will find a way to twist his sincere question into something off topic.

Then you came here and continued with the same attitude:

> A pack of trolls attacked this question

> the obtuse trolls are having a field day

I didn't see your question originally, and only found its existance by reference from this meta questions.  After reading it and looking at the history, I too have now developed a *screw you* attitude.  As Matt Young said above ***Step 1: Don't be a dick***.  You were, so now I'm going go downvote and vote to delete your original question.  It's not about your question anymore, but about your attitude and disrespect, and therefore wanting to punish you by making sure you don't get what you came here for.  This is basically the high-tech way to say *screw you* here.

Next time, keep in mind that it's nobody's job to answer your question.  People answer here because that is how they choose to spend their free time.  If a question doesn't fit the site well, would be too much trouble to answer, the OP is thumbing his nose at us with poor quality and exhibits lack of attention to detail, or is just being a dick, we're going to go find some other question to spend our time answering.

Comment: "I too have now developed a screw you attitude."

That says more about you. Perhaps you should have kept that to yourself.

Comment: Your attempt at appologetics doesn't actually explain why it's okay for you to be a dick to me and why my acceptable question is unacceptable when you choose to be a dick to me.